# opening shinyproxy-app via iFrame kills shinyproxy

Tags: r, iframe, shiny, shinyproxy

After having published my Shiny app via ShinyProxy and Docker with some success, I am now trying to integrate it via an iFrame.

Unfortunately, my app always crashes when it is called via the iFrame. It even goes so far that a simple restart of nginx and shinyproxy is not enough - I have to restart the whole server for the app to work again.

If I call up the app normally via the direct URL, everything works flawlessly. Slowly, but it works.

Could it be because my server is currently scaled comparatively small and my app is comparatively compute intensive? My server has 4 vCores, 8 GB RAM (contabo, VPS S).

I have checked the RAM level and it is indeed very high (close to 100%).

Could it actually be that the Prozess is being killed simply because of the RAM?

I honestly don't know exactly which code could help you find the problem. So I'll just wait and see and then post what you can use.

Thank you and best regards

---

service shinyproxy status (after using iFrame)

```
shinyproxy.service - ShinyProxy
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shinyproxy.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sat 2021-09-25 00:53:46 CEST; 5s ago
    Process: 3200 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar (>
   Main PID: 3200 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Sep 25 00:53:37 vmdX.contaboserver.net java[3200]: 2021-09-25 00:53:37.213 >
Sep 25 00:53:37 vmdX.contaboserver.net java[3200]: 2021-09-25 00:53:37.231 >
Sep 25 00:53:38 vmdX.contaboserver.net java[3200]: 2021-09-25 00:53:38.426 >
Sep 25 00:53:38 vmdX.contaboserver.net java[3200]: 2021-09-25 00:53:38.681 >
Sep 25 00:53:38 vmdX.contaboserver.net java[3200]: 2021-09-25 00:53:38.702 >
Sep 25 00:53:38 vmdX.contaboserver.net java[3200]: 2021-09-25 00:53:38.814 >
Sep 25 00:53:38 vmdX.contaboserver.net java[3200]: 2021-09-25 00:53:38.882 >
Sep 25 00:53:38 vmdX.contaboserver.net java[3200]: 2021-09-25 00:53:38.987 >
Sep 25 00:53:46 vmdX.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: shinyproxy.service: Main>
Sep 25 00:53:46 vmdX.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: shinyproxy.service: Fail>
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```